# Wrap Elements around a fixed centered element

Tags: html, css

I created a DIV without fixed with - just let it take 100% of its parent. Now I want to use a dash as a centered element. The Dash should always appear exactly in the middle of the div. There should be not fix-sized elements around that dash who kind of float around it.
Is there any way to do it ?

HTML

```
<div>
  <span>Element #1</span>
  <span class="centered">-</span>
  <span>Element #2</span>
</div>
```

I tried to set the centered Element to Absolute which will always keep it in the middle of the DIV (with text-align center), BUT then I cant let the items around it. Element #1 could contain 20 signs why Element #2 could only be 3 characters big.

Any ideas are appriciated, besides trying to fix it with a classic table or using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pardon if I misunderstood your question, but what about CSS tables? Using `text-align` in the sample below isn't mandatory, it just centers the example texts.

```css
.t {
  background: thistle;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.t > .centered {
  width: 1px; /*Will resize*/
}
.t > span {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <span>Element with longer content #1</span>
  <span class="centered">-</span>
  <span>Element #2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I just added text-align:right; for Element #1 and text-align:left; for Element #2 and gabe the centered class a padding: 0 2em; and it works like a charm ... I had the same solution once before - but somehow I messed up, guess I forgot the display:table-cell on all spans. Thanks Nit :)